# API GET method doesn't store data in the property in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, api, xamarin.forms, get

Data is being retrieve from the API succesfully, as I can see it here,
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrSwX.png)
and then goes to the [jsonstring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AYSG.png), but never gets to the [CantGet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33tfu.png) variable

I need it to be store in my property so I can use the value.

This is my API return:
[{"CantPremio":"70"}

Then this is my property:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;


namespace ServLottery
{
    public class GetCantPremio
    {
        public long CantPremio { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the Get task

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ServLottery
{
    public class RestClient
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public async Task<T> Get<T>(string URL)
        {
            try
            {
                
                var response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var jsonstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonstring);
                }

            }
            catch 
            {
            }
            return default(T);
        }

    }
}
```

Finally this is the call:

```
private async void GetCantDisponible()
        {
            try
            {
                RestClient client = new RestClient();
                var CantGet = await client.Get<GetCantPremio>("https://servicentroapi.azurewebsites.net/api/GetNumber");
                if (CantGet != null)
                {
                    PremiosCantLocal = CantGet.CantPremio.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Don't paste images of code. Put the actual code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like kelvin said, set the `List<T>` for the json array. And then foreach the collection to get the `CantPremio`.

RestClient:

```
public class RestClient
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public async Task<List<T>> Get<T>(string URL)
    {
        try
        {

            var response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var jsonstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var s = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(jsonstring);

                return s;
            }

        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return default(List<T>);
    }

}
```

GetCantDisponible:

```
private async void GetCantDisponible()
    {
        try
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient();
            var CantGet = await client.Get<GetCantPremio>("https://servicentroapi.azurewebsites.net/api/GetNumber");
            if (CantGet != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in CantGet)
                {
                    var PremiosCantLocal = item.CantPremio.ToString();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The api you are accessing is returning an array. So you must deserialize not a simple object but a list.

```
return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(jsonstring);
```

Replace the line that deserializes with this one. Should solve the problem

Comment: Shows error 

CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to 'T'

Comment: You must also change the return of the method. The signature must be: public async Task<List<T>> Get<T>(string URL)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, your API is returning an array but you're trying to deserialize it to a single instance. I'd suggest changing the call site of your client to pass a list for the type parameter:

```
List<GetCantPremio> CantGet = await client.Get<List<GetCantPremio>>("https://servicentroapi.azurewebsites.net/api/GetNumber");
```

Note that `CantGet` is now a List. If you are only looking for one object you could just add on a `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
GetCantPremio CantGet = await client.Get<List<GetCantPremio>>("https://servicentroapi.azurewebsites.net/api/GetNumber")?.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks. How would it work in a case where I have two values instead of just one? I thought that was the idea of having the properties named exactly the same as the items from the api, so it will automatically assign the value to each of them